# Listening to default activity transition

Tags: android, activity-transition

I'm trying to add `TransitionListener` to default activity transition like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        getWindow().getEnterTransition().addListener(new TransitionAdapter());
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private class TransitionAdapter implements Transition.TransitionListener {
    @Override
    public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
        Log.i("transition", "onTransitionStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
        Log.i("transition", "onTransitionEnd");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {
        Log.i("transition", "onTransitionCancel");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {
        Log.i("transition", "onTransitionPause");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {
        Log.i("transition", "onTransitionResume");
    }
}
```

This how I start activity:
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, LoginActivity.class);

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Bundle options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity).toBundle();
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.SIGN_IN, options);
    } else {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodes.SIGN_IN);
    }
```

The problem is no callback is ever called on **real device**. It works on genymotion though. Is there some additional setup required for that?

DISCLAIMER: I test it on lolipop running device

Comment: Are you calling your activity using ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation?

Comment: No - I don't have any shared elements

Comment: Wow, thats an answer. I dint' know I could use it without shared elements. Bundle options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity).toBundle(); Please make it an answer so I could accept it

Comment: Turns out that ```ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity).toBundle()``` helps on genymotion but not on real device

Answer (score 0):

Found out it doesn't work on 5.0 but got fixed on 5.1 so it's clearly an android bug. I don't know a workaround for this though. I've restricted transitions to minimum API 22.